# Unable to upgrade ubuntu 18.04, Error Could not download the upgrades

Tags: 16.04, upgrade, 18.04

There is nothing wrong with my internet connective, I have tried several times.

Check the Error msg --> [Failed to fetch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dsrFi.png)

Comment: I can't copy/paste from your picture into a browser to look at the problem, it appears you are using a valid mirror (that is currently a day behind), so I'd copy & paste your file into a browser and see if you can download it there (I suspect you won't be able to),, ie. it's a current issue with your mirror, so you can wait & try again later, ask them to fix, or use a different mirror (https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archivemirrors).  If you'd copied the error message in text I'd have been more specific.  (https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/libmozjs-52-0)

Answer (score 1):

Find the line in `/etc/apt/sources.list` that has http://ny-mirrors.evowise.com/ubuntu/pool/main/m/mozjs52/libmozjs-52-0_52.9.1-0ubuntu0.18.04.1_amd64.deb in it and comment it out by preceding it with a `#` character. This line is preventing your system from being upgraded from Ubuntu 16.04 to Ubuntu 18.04.

Open `/etc/apt/sources.list` for editing in nano text editor.

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Press the keyboard combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> and after that press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to save the changes in sources.list.

Press the keyboard combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> to exit nano.

Then run this two commands to update the latest list of software.

```
sudo apt update
```